# Fresh ReactJS project stuck at starting the development server

Tags: reactjs, npm

I am running a fresh react project with no single line of code written by me.

All I did was:

```
npx create-react-app my-app

npm install

npm start
```

The browser window opens and within my console window I see "Starting the development server". It is stuck there, have been keeping it up for over an hour with no progress.

I looked at different SO threads as well as many suggestions on other platforms. From limiting the RAM available to using another port, closing all browser windows, rebooting my machine - nothing helped.

Do you have any suggestions for troubleshooting?
Running on macOS 13.1 on M1 Pro.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It was the directory I started the project in. Using spaces and several special characters seems to break react as well es next.js which I tried next.